# How do I add attributes to a component's RenderFragment?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to remove the need for the div in the (simplified) BasicComponent below...

```
<div data-ref="blah">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

So in pseudo code the component would be defined like this...

```
@ChildContent data-ref="blah"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

So when used like this

```
<BasicComponent>
    <a href="" />
</BasicComponent
```

the rendered html looks like

```
<a href="" data-ref="blah" />
```

So, in summary I'm looking to remove the div and find a way of adding attributes to the supplied ChildContent RenderFragment. The data-ref is just an example of an attribute that is defined in the component and I'd like to add it to the outermost node of the ChildContent RenderFragment.

Comment: [Probably me being stupid] You show the rendered content as `<a href="" data-ref="blah" />`.  I see no `div`?  What data type is data-ref?  Does `a` have an attribute called `data-ref`?

Comment: No, I probably should have repeated the question's title in the question somewhere...  I'm looking to remove the div and find a way of adding attributes to the Component's passed in RenderFragment.  The data-ref was just an example of an attribute that is defined in the component and is added to whatever the outermost node of the ChildContent RenderFragment is.  Will update the question

Comment: What if the user only supplied text as the child content - you can't add an attribute to that. Or more than one element - which one would you add your data-ref to? This seems like a mistake in the design at this point. The answers provided are strictly correct, you don't have a built in way to do that - and any workaround is messy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can without some hoop jumping and writing the whole thing in `RenderTreeBuilder` methods: which I assure you, you won't want to do.

`ChildContent` is a `RenderFragment` i.e. a delegate.  You can see the definition below.  It's a code block within the parent that gets run in the context of the parent by the Renderer.  It doesn't have access to the `BasicComponent` instance.

```cs
__builder.OpenComponent<global::SO76538378.Pages.BasicComponent>(8);
__builder.AddAttribute(9, "ChildContent", (global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment)((__builder2) => {
    __builder2.AddMarkupContent(10, "<a href></a>");
    }
));
__builder.CloseComponent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently Blazor is limited in this way - at least I don't know of a way to alter the provided RenderFragment after receiving it.

For sure theere are many possibilities to overcome this, for example using css or js to add the attribute later on, or simply using a switch-case inside to create the desired HTML tags yourself after providing a Parameter like "HtmlTagType" which could offer an Enum for "a, div, span, p" or whatever values.

I guess the easiest way would be (beside of using the div you don't want to use anymore) to use a `parameterized RenderFragment` instead.

Simply change your Component code to:

```cs
@ChildContent(dataRef)

@code {

    // you can extract this to it's own class if you like to
    public struct DataRef {

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    // set this the way you like, probably you alread have this logic
    private DataRef dataRef = new DataRef { Value = "blah" };

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<DataRef> ChildContent { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And simply use it as you suggested:

```html
<BasicComponent>
    <a href="#" data-ref="@context.Value" >
        click me! 
    </a>
</BasicComponent>
```

Which renders to: [image]

The downside here is that you have to know the attribute's name to set it, as Blazor does not allow code directly inside the tags to for example add attributes. But you're now able to use the value of the BaseComponent and place it inside the a-tag without the need of the div-tag anymore.

EDIT: just fiddled around and it's also possible to directly use a `Dictionary<string,object>` as RenderFragment parameter and fill it with your attributes (e.g. `{ "data-ref", "blah" }`). You can then use it with `@attributes="@context"` and it works the same as before ;)